# Qt deployement on different windows version

Tags: c++, windows, qt, windows-7, windows-10

I work with :
- windows 10
- Qt 5.6 - msvc2013_64

I installed successfully my software on windows 10.

I try to do the same on windows 7, by copy the install folder.

I have an error

> this application failed to start because it could not find or load the
>   qt platform plugin windows

I have the folder /plateforms in my .exe directory.
It contains qwindows.dll.

Have I to compile my software on windows 7 ?

Any idea ?

Comment: `/plateforms` - typo

Comment: Start with official documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Comment: no, you're wrong , it' platforms.
no help with this link. if you read what i write, you knew that I have already a version of my soft.
My problem is about windows os

Comment: I think that some DLLs are missing. Use windeployqt.exe and check with the dependency walker of Qt

Comment: Add to your question a structure of your deployment dir. There are no telepathist. And show a content of your `qt.conf` file.

Comment: Btw, this link helped me once: http://www.tripleboot.org/?p=536 - really cool research.

Comment: I already used windeployqt.exe, but no success. what I don't understant is that my install folder work with windows 8/10, but no with windows 7

Comment: 1. It's /platforms. 2. Use Dependency Walker 3. Check if you installed the appropriate redist package. 4. Check for e.g. libEGL.dll in your path.

Comment: I copy all dll from my_version_qt\bin, and all folder from my_version_qt\plugins. No success

Comment: @IAmInPLS **The suggestion to use the dependency walker pops up again and again, but it's useless 99% of the time**. Qt is not linked to the plugins - it loads them dynamically and resolves function addresses at runtime. The plugins aren't the classical demand-load DLLs that you'd see in dependency walker output.